# Does anyone know what plant is it?

Tags: trees, houseplants, fruit-trees

Is it a tree? Is it fruit? It never bear any fruits.[image]

[image]

Comment: How tall is it and what part of the world are you in?

Comment: It’s about 60cm, I am from ASEAN

Answer (score 1):

This is a member of the Ficus family.  If the leaves are thin then it is likely to be [Ficus benjamina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_benjamina).  Keys to identification are:

- when a leaf is broken white sap comes out
- pale dots on the stem

This plant can get quite large when grown outside but this one appears to be growing in very low light.  Under low light conditions it does not set fruit but a mature specimen in good light will produce round brown fruit about the size of a pea that are not edible.

Comment: I added better picture for you